# Count number of raster cells cover by shapefile

Tags: qgis, raster

[image]

I have a raster image of Alberta province (1km * 1km resolution ), I put the other shapefile (i.e., grounds, hospital, schools etc) in QGIS . I want to calculate the number of raster cells (1km * 1km ) covered by ground, hospital etc.

Is there any way to find the how many raster cells covered by each required area?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing your data? Try Zonal statistics with `Statistics to calculate = Count`

Comment: Please have a look on it again I edited it now -bera

Comment: Did you try zonal statistics